# Converting + to checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm trying to create a check box, in JavaScript, every time a user press +
I did it in that way

```
function Selected(e) {
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);

    if(character=='+'){
        var t1= new Array();

        t1[0]=document.createElement('input');
        t1[0].type='checkbox';
        t1[0].name='checkbox1';
        t1[0].value = "value";
        document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(t1[0]);

    }
}
```

but it shows the checkbox in the next line and the + as well.
Is there any way to delete the + and show only the checkbox in the same line?

**PS:** unfortunately some `execCommand` are supported only by IE, that's why I didn't use

```
document.execCommand ('InsertInputCheckbox', false, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Append it this way:

```
function Selected(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if(String.fromCharCode(code) == '+') {
        var t1 = [];

        t1[0] = document.createElement('input');
        t1[0].type='checkbox';
        t1[0].name='checkbox1';
        t1[0].value = "value";
        document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(t1[0]);
    }
}
```

code revised for some optimization, 
[fiddle for solution](http://jsfiddle.net/bFEyx/)

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned your code a little bit and added a fiddle for your perusal: http://jsfiddle.net/jLEa5/

```
    function Selected(e) {
        var code, evt, character;

        evt = e || window.event;
        if (evt.keyCode) {
            code = evt.keyCode;
        }
        else if (evt.which) {
            code = evt.which;
        }

        character = String.fromCharCode(code);

        if(character=='+') {
            var t1 = [], el;

            el = document.createElement('input');
            el.type='checkbox';
            el.name='checkbox1';
            el.value = "value";
            t1.push(el);
            document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(t1[0]);
        }
    }


window.addEventListener('keypress', Selected);​
```

Comment: Could you update that jsfiddle with your current code that you're using?

Comment: Thank you very much both of you but I'm still getting the + because my div is contenteditable="true" so when I press the + is still appearing. Sorry, I didn't mention it before. Really sorry.